# Filter a tuple with another tuple in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples that is created with the `zip` function. `zip` is bringing together four lists: `narrative`, `subject`, `activity`, and `filer`, each of which is just a list of 0s and 1s. Let's say those four lists look like this:

```
narrative = [0, 0, 0, 0]
subject = [1, 1, 0, 1]
activity = [0, 0, 0, 1]
filer = [0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Now, I'm `zip`ing them together to get a list of boolean values indicating if any of them are `True`.

`ny_nexus = [True if sum(x) > 0 else False for x in zip(narrative, subject, activity, filer)]`

The problem I'm having now, is getting a second list of tuples for which the names of the variables is returned if it had a 1 during the iteration. I imagine it would look something like this:

```
variables = ("narrative", "subject", "activity", "filer")
reason = [", ".join([some code to filter a tuple]) for x in zip(narrative, subject, activity, filer)]
```

I just can't figure out how I'd go about this. My desired output would look like this:

```
reason
# ["subject", "subject, filer", "filer", "subject, activity"]
```

I'm somewhat new to Python, so I apologize if the solution is easy.

Comment: By the way, you can say `ny_nexus = [sum(x) > 0 for x in zip...]`

Comment: Always appreciate more concise code. Thanks

Comment: Even better, use the `any()` built-in function ;) `any([0, 0, 0]) == False`, `any([0, 1, 0]) == True`. So, `ny_nexus = [any(x) for x in zip...]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store tuples in a dictionary for a cleaner solution:

```
tups = {'narrative': narrative,
        'subject': subject,
        'activity': activity,
        'filer': filer}
```

The solution:

```
reason = [', '.join(k for k, b in zip(tups, x) if b) for x in zip(*tups.values())]
```

It can also be written using [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
from itertools import compress
reason = [', '.join(compress(tups, x)) for x in zip(*tups.values())]
```

---

Solutions above do not preserve the order of tuples, e.g. they can return something like

```
['subject', 'filer, subject', 'filer', 'activity, subject']
```

If you need the order to be preserved, use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) as shown below:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

tups = OrderedDict([
    ('narrative', narrative),
    ('subject', subject),
    ('activity', activity),
    ('filer', filer)
])

# The result is ['subject', 'subject, filer', 'filer', 'subject, activity']
```

***EDIT:*** The solution that doesn't involve dictionaries:

```
from itertools import compress
reason = [', '.join(compress(variables, x))
          for x in zip(narrative, subject, activity, filer)]
```

Consider using dictionaries if the `zip(...)` call no longer fits on one line.

Comment: Thus far, this is the only solution that is working. However, it is the one I understand the least. Can you explain what `compress` does, along with what the role `*` plays in `zip(*tups.values())` please?

Comment: @vaultah: I don't see how a dictionary or OrderedDict makes this any cleaner. You've already got `compress()`, why not just feed it OP's `variables` tuple?

Comment: @brittenb: If you look at the documentation for `compress()`, you will see that it does pretty much exactly what you're looking for. It selects elements of one sequence based on whether the corresponding elements of another sequence are true.

Comment: @JohnY Yeah, I just pulled up the documentation for it and it's pretty self explanatory. Based on that it seems the right solution to this problem is `reason = [", ".join(compress(variables, x)) for x in zip(narrative, subject, activity, filer)]`

Comment: @brittenb: yeah, you can do that. Though I still believe that a dictionary makes it cleaner.

Comment: @brittenb: Exactly right. No need in this case to mess with dictionaries or the asterisk operator. (It will be handy to know about, and the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) goes over it, but you can worry about it later.)

Comment: @vaultah I agree that it's an important concept to keep in mind for this type of task. For me, the order of values is not important, so it's a bit cleaner to remove the extra lines of code. But were the order of the values important, then this would definitely be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip(narrative, subject, activity, filer)` basically transposes the matrix (your list of lists of equal length make up the matrix).  You then enumerate through these to find the location `n` of where the flag is true and index the appropriate variable.

```
narrative = [0, 0, 0, 0]
subject = [1, 1, 0, 1]
activity = [0, 0, 0, 1]
filer = [0, 1, 1, 0]
variables = ("narrative", "subject", "activity", "filer")
# ========================================================

new_list = [[variables[n] for n, flag in enumerate(indicators) if flag] 
            for indicators in zip(narrative, subject, activity, filer)]
>>> new_list
[['subject'], ['subject', 'filer'], ['filer'], ['subject', 'activity']]
```

To see the transpose:

```
>>> [i for i in zip(narrative, subject, activity, filer)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the filtering aspect of the comprehension syntax to get 
your vaiable English name only if the respective flag is True:

```
variables = ("narrative", "subject", "activity", "filer")
[tuple (name for flag, name in zip(x, variables) if x)  for x in zip(narrative, subject, activity, filer)]
```

That said, there is something fishy about your approach - you'd probbly be (far) better of with an object oriented approach there, instead of trying to manually coordinate independent sequences of variables for each of your subjects.

Comment: This approach makes sense to me, but since `x` will always evaluate as Truthy, it returns all values in `variables`. Can you elaborate on your object-oriented approach? I'm not married to the way I'm currently doing it and am always willing to try new methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
    narrative = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    subject = [1, 1, 0, 1]
    activity = [0, 0, 0, 1]
    filer = [0, 1, 1, 0]
    variables = ("narrative", "subject", "activity", "filer")
    ny_nexus = [True if sum(x) > 0 else False for x in zip(narrative, subject, activity, filer)]
    output = []
    [[output.append(variables[j]) if t==1 else None for j,t in enumerate(x)] for x in zip(narrative, subject, activity, filer)]
    print ny_nexus
    print output
```

Of course you could just do the following without using list comprehensions:

```
    narrative = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    subject = [1, 1, 0, 1]
    activity = [0, 0, 0, 1]
    filer = [0, 1, 1, 0]
    variables = ("narrative", "subject", "activity", "filer")
    ny_nexus = [True if sum(x) > 0 else False for x in zip(narrative, subject, activity, filer)]
    output = []
    for x in zip(narrative, subject, activity, filer):
        for j,t in enumerate(x):
            output.append(variables[j])
    print ny_nexus
    print output
```

Comment: This approach also makes sense to me, but it is returning `None` for all values. Any idea why?

Comment: The results of ny_nexus in the above code are actually useless. The useful results are only in output. In fact, you could change the name of ny_nexus to tmp or something and disregard it. The above code would be required in addition to your following statement:

ny_nexus = [True if sum(x) > 0 else False for x in zip(narrative, subject, activity, filer)]

Comment: Updated answer to reflect